# TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, json, python-requests, json-rpc

I am trying to get a value from a response object in a dictionary, but I keep running into this error, am I wrong in thinking you `__getitem__` is more commonly used for indexing in classes?

Here is the code:

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "http://public.coindaddy.io:4000/api/"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('rpc', '1234')

payload = {
  "method": "get_running_info",
  "params": {},
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 0,
}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers,   auth=auth)


print("respone is: ", response['result'])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The response object is not a dictionary, you cannot use indexing on it.

If the API returns a [JSON response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content), you need to use the [`response.json()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) to decode it to a Python object:

```
data = response.json()
print("respone is: ", data['result'])
```

Note that you don't have to encode the request JSON data either; you could just use the `json` argument to the `request.post()` method here; this also sets the Content-Type header for you:

```
response = requests.post(url, json=payload, auth=auth)
```

Last but not least, if the API uses JSONRPC as the protocol, you could use the [`jsonrpc-requests` project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonrpc-requests) to proxy method calls for you:

```
from jsonrpc_requests import Server

url = "http://public.coindaddy.io:4000/api/"
server = Server(url, auth=('rpc', '1234'))

result = server.get_running_info()
```

Comment: if i could +2 I would really appreciate this answer mate.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your source code a bit like this :

```
 response = requests.post(url, json=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers,   auth=auth).json()

 print("respone is: ", response['result'].encode('utf-8'))
```

It's true that response object alone can't be indexed instead for that purpose you need to return info in `json format` (in order parse response information ) which you can do so using `json()` and 
Here in order to get proper string you must encode it with utf-8 (other wise your output will be something like this -u'LikeThis)

Comment: you should also add an explanation like others.

Comment: Sure, I encountered this error today, I will add a better explanation later.