# Python TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'getitem'

Tags: python, json, instagram-api

I have this piece of code that gives me the error message:

```
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1'
response = requests.get('https://jsonbin.io/b/59d0f30408be13271f7df29c').json()
APP_ACCESS_TOKEN = response['access_token']
print APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

def self_info():
    request_url = (BASE_URL + 'users/self/?access_token=%s') % (APP_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    print 'GET request url : %s' % (request_url)
    user_info = requests.get(request_url)

    if user_info['meta']['code'] == 200:
        print 'tabish'
    else:
        print 'Status code other than 200 received!'

self_info()
```

This results in the following error message:

> TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Take a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665659/typeerror-response-object-has-no-attribute-getitem).

Answer (score 1):

To check status code of get() or any requests you need to check status_code of response so you need to replace `if user_info['meta']['code'] == 200:` with `if user_info.status_code == 200:`.

Comment: No it is still not working.. 
It shows 
 if user_info.status_code== 200:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'